# Which graphics library is better for embedded linux?

Tags: graphics, embedded, libraries, embedded-linux

Which graphics library is best for developing GUI for character LCD or simple graphics LCD for embedded linux. ? which has better performance and support ?

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: What platform / chipset?  DirectFB is supported on a lot of platforms.  Also, what Borealid said.

Comment: I want to use on TI's Davinci platform DM6443 processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitmap converter,charecter converters for developing applications in Charecter LCD or GLCD.

Comment: i don't want any converter .. please first read the question carefully